# Qt Designer PyQt5 overwrite CloseEvent child window don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have three windows designed in QtDesigner. The main window calls the two childs windows using buttons. If I close the main window the childs windows also close, I did this by overwriting the closeEvent in the main window. I need to implement some stuff in the closeEvent of the child window so I overwritten the closeEvent of the child class but it does nothing. Please help.

Class of the main window made in Qt Designer

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ventanaPrincipal(object):
    def setupUi(self, ventanaPrincipal):
        ventanaPrincipal.setObjectName("ventanaPrincipal")
        ventanaPrincipal.resize(267, 238)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ventanaPrincipal)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.buttonVentana1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.buttonVentana1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 141, 25))
        self.buttonVentana1.setObjectName("buttonVentana1")
        self.buttonVentana2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.buttonVentana2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 141, 25))
        self.buttonVentana2.setObjectName("buttonVentana2")
        ventanaPrincipal.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(ventanaPrincipal)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 267, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        ventanaPrincipal.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(ventanaPrincipal)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName("mainToolBar")
        ventanaPrincipal.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(ventanaPrincipal)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        ventanaPrincipal.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(ventanaPrincipal)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ventanaPrincipal)

    def retranslateUi(self, ventanaPrincipal):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ventanaPrincipal.setWindowTitle(_translate("ventanaPrincipal", "ventanaPrincipal"))
        self.buttonVentana1.setText(_translate("ventanaPrincipal", "Ventana 1"))
        self.buttonVentana2.setText(_translate("ventanaPrincipal", "Ventana 2"))
```

Class of first child window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_subVen1(object):
    def setupUi(self, subVen1):
        subVen1.setObjectName("subVen1")
        subVen1.resize(320, 347)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(subVen1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 141, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(subVen1)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")

        self.retranslateUi(subVen1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subVen1)

    def retranslateUi(self, subVen1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subVen1.setWindowTitle(_translate("subVen1", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("subVen1", "MIAU MIAU"))
```

Class of second child window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_subVen2(object):
    def setupUi(self, subVen2):
        subVen2.setObjectName("subVen2")
        subVen2.resize(320, 304)
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(subVen2)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 256, 192))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(subVen2)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 20, 121, 17))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(subVen2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(subVen2)

    def retranslateUi(self, subVen2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        subVen2.setWindowTitle(_translate("subVen2", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("subVen2", "Guau Guau"))
```

File that calls the other three.

```
import sys
#import classes-----------------------
from HMIs.ventanaprincipal import Ui_ventanaPrincipal, QtWidgets
from HMIs.subventana1 import Ui_subVen1
from HMIs.subventana2 import Ui_subVen2
# hijaSub1 inherits the first child window class made by the QtDesigner
#override child closeEvent
class hijaSub1(Ui_subVen1):
   def closeEvent(self, event):
      print("X is clicked")


class multiVen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent=None)
        self.ui =Ui_ventanaPrincipal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.subV1=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.subV2=QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #Conect signals whith slots--------------------
        self.ui.buttonVentana1.clicked.connect(self.muestraVentana1)
        self.ui.buttonVentana2.clicked.connect(self.muestraVentana2)
    # slots-----------------------------------------
    def muestraVentana1(self):
        self.wid1=hijaSub1()
        self.wid1.setupUi(self.subV1)
        self.subV1.show() 

    def muestraVentana2(self):
        self.wid2=Ui_subVen2()
        self.wid2.setupUi(self.subV2)
        self.subV2.show()
#Close all windows whith X button of main window
#override main closeEvent        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.subV1.close()
        self.subV2.close()
        event.accept()


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=0
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=multiVen()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `closeEvent` method has the classes that inherit from QWidget, in which case the daughter classes `Sub1`, `Ui_subVen1`, `Ui_subVen2` inherit from object, not from `QWidget`.

If you want to implement `closeEvent` in windows, create a class that uses the window view (`Ui_xxx`) and inherits from `QWidget`.

```
class hijaSub1(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_subVen1):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("X is clicked: hijaSub1")

class hijaSub2(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_subVen2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("X is clicked: hijaSub2")

class multiVen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent=None)
        self.ui =Ui_ventanaPrincipal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.subV1=hijaSub1()
        self.subV2=hijaSub2()
        #Conect signals whith slots--------------------
        self.ui.buttonVentana1.clicked.connect(self.muestraVentana1)
        self.ui.buttonVentana2.clicked.connect(self.muestraVentana2)
    # slots-----------------------------------------
    def muestraVentana1(self):
        self.subV1.show() 

    def muestraVentana2(self):
        self.subV2.show()
#Close all windows whith X button of main window
#override main closeEvent        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.subV1.close()
        self.subV2.close()
        event.accept()


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=0
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=multiVen()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```